# How to change default root validator response in Pydantic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Assume that I have a simple Pydantic model as,

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator, ValidationError


class Foo(BaseModel):
    age: int
    country: str

    @root_validator()
    @classmethod
    def validate_age_min(cls, values: dict):
        if values["age"] < 18 and values["country"] == "India":
            raise ValueError("Some Error")
        return values
```

and I'm trying to validate my input as below,

```py
try:
    Foo(age=15, country="India")
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e.errors())
```

This will return the result as,

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "__root__"
        ],
        "msg": "Some Error",
        "type": "value_error"
    }
]
```

How can I change the value of ***`__root__`*** to something else in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by [this](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/729) discussion and [this](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/817/files) implementation, I would say it's not possible to change `__root__` to anything else.

However, in a case like yours, you could work around this limitation with a regular `validator()`, for example, like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class Foo(BaseModel):
    country: str
    age: int

    @validator("age")
    def validate_age_min(cls, v: int, values: dict):
        if values["country"] == "India" and v < 18:
            raise ValueError("Some Error")
        return v
```

Now, the validation:

```py
try:
    Foo(age=15, country="India")
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e.errors())
```

will show an error like this:

```json
[
  {
    "loc": [
      "age"
    ],
    "msg": "Some Error",
    "type": "value_error"
  }
]
```

which might be better suited for your use case.

The only caveat (see end of first section in the Validator [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)):

> Validation is done in the order fields are defined.

Which means, in your model *definition*, `country` **must** go before `age` for this to work.

However, the order of fields doesn't matter when the model gets *instantiated*.

See also [Field Ordering](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#field-ordering).